# How to represent from 16bit color depth to 18bit color depth?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to represent 18bit color depth to 16bit color depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056879/how-to-represent-18bit-color-depth-to-16bit-color-depth)

I'm porting a software that build from 16-bit color depth device to 18-bit color depth device? How can I represent the 18-bit color depth? Thanks.

Comment: I would edit your original rather than make an almost duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056879/how-18-bit-device-display-bitmap

Comment: edit the original post instead of a posting a new one.

Comment: Please do not create duplicate questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056879/how-to-represent-18bit-color-depth-to-16bit-color-depth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: This is just an edit of my answer to your previous question, since the two are so similar - you just have to reverse the process.

---

You will first of all have to access each of the colour components (i.e. extract the R value, the G value, and the B value).  The way to do this will depend totally on the way that the colour is stored in memory.  If it is stored as RGB, with 5-6-5 bits for the components, you could use something like this:

```
blueComponent  = (colour & 0x3F);
greenComponent = (colour >>  6) & 0x3F;
redComponent   = (colour >> 12) & 0x3F;
```

This will extract the colour components for you, then you can use the method outlined above to convert each of the components (I presume 18-bit will use 6 bits per component):

```
blueComponent  = (blueComponent  / 64.0) * 32;
//greenComponent = (greenComponent / 64.0) * 64;    //not needed
redComponent   = (redComponent   / 64.0) * 32;
```

Note that with the above code, it is important that you use *64.0*, or some other method that will ensure that your program represents the number as a floating point number.  Then to combine the components into your 18-bit colour, use:

```
colour = (redComponent << 11) | (greenComponent << 5) | blueComponent;
```